# Single User after renaming an MS-SQL database

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, smo

I am using help of SqlServer.Management.Smo to rename an attached MS-SQL database.

```
Dim db As New Database = ActiveSQLServer.Databases(OLD_NAME)
db.ExecuteNonQuery("ALTER DATABASE " & OLD_NAME & " SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE")
db.ExecuteNonQuery("ALTER DATABASE " & OLD_NAME & " MODIFY NAME = " & NEW_NAME)
```

The problem is that after renaming the database is set as a Single User.

So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2nd statement is setting it to single user.

Comment: I must be joking... right?
I will never ever copy & paste again!

Comment: LOL - easiest question I've seen in ages. Don't worry, we've all done that at some point. :-)